# Browser compatibility display using ticker

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, ticker

I wish to show users a warning ticker kind of thing on top of my page which displays a message if the user is not using particular versions of browser like if user is using IE6 then I wish to show the message that "This browser is not supported, so please upgrade".

The question over here is first how to check which browser user is using and second how to create Javascript/Jquery or anything simpler ticker on top of the page which should be displayed only once and should have a cross button for hiding it.

Comment: You have numerous implementations for this exact purpose out there, just Goog harder (AFAIK one is even implemented by default in the latest HTML5 Boilerplate)

Comment: nowadays it is about feature detection rather than browser detection. see jquery support

Comment: @roXon yes, there is an implementation in HTML5 Boilerplate, http://html5boilerplate.com

Answer (score 1):

What browsers/versions do you want to display messages for?

If you're just doing this for older IEs, you could add the HTML that includes the message and add a "old-ie" class to it's parent container. Add a selector to your main stylesheet for `.old-ie` and give it the `display: none;` property.

Using conditional comments, you can override the main stylesheet in ie6.css, ie7.css (or in the inline CSS) and add another selector for `.old-ie`, but this time give it `display: block;`.

If you're wanting to target older versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc. you'll need to use feature detection as mikakun mentioned above.